# HTML form input auto-Indentation

Tags: html, forms, internationalization, indentation

I want to use HTML's Form text-box.
The problem is that I want my users to write in both RTL and LTR languages.
Is there any option to auto Indent the user's input, inside the text-box (while writing) from right to left? (as done in google)

```
<input type="text" name="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Thanks,

Comment: Auto indent? You mean you want it to recognize the user's language and change the direction accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to determinate the language written by looping through all chars (A-z = ltr, 1-9 neutral and other rtl or something). Then apply the 'direction: rtl' css if its a rtl language.

Comment: Yeah, you should probably recalculate on each keydown event

Answer (score -1):

you can use ajax to control the chars used via a server side script (ex. php); then call a specific js function that change the dir property of input tag.

Comment: AJAX? PHP? Specific js function?